# Unexpected generated emberjs code

Tags: ember.js, model, ember-cli

I'm trying to go through an ember cli tutorial. When I generate a model with:

`ember generate model user`

, the tutorial says I should get a user.js class like:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
export default
DS.Model.extend({
});
```

but I get:

```
import Model from 'ember-data/model';

export default Model.extend({

});
```

I'm not sure what I may have done to cause this. Do I have different version of Ember CLI, have I perhaps missed something in my setup, or something else? I'm not sure if I can ignore it and continue or if I should resolve this issue first.

Thanks,

Bob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can feel relieved, as you didn't cause this in anyway.

This is just a different way that is used to reference to Model, attr, belongsTo, and hasMany. Previously, you would access them directly as references on the DS object.

Read this [blog post](http://emberjs.com/blog/2016/01/12/ember-data-2-3-released.html) for a full breakdown.

I'll add a bit of code below for easier reference.

Instead of the following:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  prop: DS.attr('string'),
  prop: DS.hasMany('model-ref'),
  prop: DS.belongsTo('model-ref')
});
```

Use

```
import Model from 'ember-data/model';
import attr from 'ember-data/attr';
import { hasMany, belongsTo } from 'ember-data/relationships';

export default Model.extend({
  prop: attr('string'),
  prop: hasMany('model-ref'),
  prop: belongsTo('model-ref')
});
```

Comment: Thank you, TameBadger. I've only been working with this for a couple of days. It's already changing too fast for this old guy. I am using Ember-CLI 2.5. So, that explains it. Thanks for the code examples.

Comment: Ah dang, no problem, discussed this in the slack community a while back, this should not even be an issue, but there is so many moving parts in this area of the dev world it seems!